# Try-with-resources: Must I throw or catch the close() method's exceptions?

Tags: java, exception

Please correct me if this is wrong:  In Java 7's try-with-resources statement, any exceptions thrown by the resource's `close()` method must be either declared as thrown by my method or I must wrap the whole try in another `try` which catches any exceptions thrown by `close()`.

If so, I have to wonder if I will make much use of it.  I certainly don't want to `throw` the exceptions thrown by `close()`, the caller won't know what to do with that.  And a `try` wrapping another `try` just to handle `close()` would not look very elegant, to me at least.

**EDIT:**  I think I accidentally asked two questions, one of which was a duplicate.

Question 1.  Do I have to declare that my method throws the exception from the `close()` method or wrap the try-with-resources in another try?  (Not answered in proposed duplicate.)

Question 2.  Is there a way to close the resource silently?  (Clearly a duplicate, so I am taking that sentence out of the question.  Hopefully this makes the question satisfactorily unique.)

Comment: Do you have a lot of resources that throw from `close()`?

Comment: Just a few, but I use them a lot (ResultSet, BufferedReader, RandomAccessFile).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Quote from [Java Language Specification ($14.20.3.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.2):

> **14.20.3.2 Extended try-with-resources**
>
> A *try-with-resources* statement with at least one catch clause and/or a finally
>   clause is called an extended try-with-resources statement.
>   The meaning of an extended try-with-resources statement:
>
> try *ResourceSpecification*
>           Block
>       *Catches*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>       *Finally*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>
> is given by the following translation to a basic  *try-with-resources* statement
>   ([§14.20.3.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.1)) nested inside a  *try-catch* or  *try-finally* or  *try-catch-finally*
>   statement:
>
> try {
>           try *ResourceSpecification*
>               Block
>       }
>       *Catches*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>       *Finally*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>
> The effect of the translation is to put the ResourceSpecification "inside" the try
>   statement. This allows a catch clause of an extended try-with-resources statement
>   to catch an exception due to the automatic initialization or closing of any resource.

So, basically, wrapper is already implemented

Answer (score 29):

From [the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

> A try-with-resources statement can have catch and finally blocks just like an ordinary try statement. In a try-with-resources statement, **any catch or finally block is run after the resources declared have been closed**.

(emphasis mine)

So you can simply do

```
try (BufferedReader br =
               new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
    return br.readLine();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // handle the exception that has been thrown by readLine() OR by close().
}
```

Comment: That approach does not solve the problem. For me the "normal" behaviour is: 1) rethrow the exception from readLine 2) Ignore the exception thrown by close. Doing it the way you propose, there is not an easy way to know if the exception is from readLine or from close.

Comment: @Rober2D2 note `IOException` has more specific subclasses (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html). It may be you'll get different ones from `readline` compared to `close`. You'd have to test it out to be sure. I would like the documentation to say specifically *which* exceptions can be expected, and not just use the more general IOException.

Answer (score 8):

You do not need to wrap the try-with-resources in another try-catch block, you simply add a catch block:

```
class Foo implements AutoCloseable {
    public void close() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}

public class Try {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        try(Foo f = new Foo()) {
            System.out.println("No op!");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to simply add the appropriate `catch (Exception e) { }` clause.  If you need to do special handling for a specific one, or you can simply catch `Exception`, if you need it much broader.

```
try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while (rs.next()) {
        String coffeeName = rs.getString("COF_NAME");
        int supplierID = rs.getInt("SUP_ID");
        float price = rs.getFloat("PRICE");

        System.out.println(coffeeName + ", " + supplierID + ", " + 
                           price + ", " + sales + ", " + total);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception while trying to through the queries. ", e);
}
```

Since it's Java 7, you can actually put multiple exceptions per catch clause, or you can simply catch the outermost exception you want.